# creating a wordpress theme: using an old theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, visual-web-developer

I want to start working on a new wordpress theme. 
Snd not sure how to start.

I find the twentytwelve theme easier to work on. 
The structure is more similar to what i want to do, and it's kinda blank. 
If I use it, will I still have the same functions and updates like the twentyfourteen theme?

what is the most common way to start building a theme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you will not have the same functionality and updated code like the twentyfourteen theme, because simply twentyfourteen is newer and compatible with WordPress 3.8 <

**I may suggest some starter themes:**

- [Underscores.me](http://underscores.me/)
- [Bones](http://themble.com/bones/)
- [Roots](http://roots.io/starter-theme/)
- [Quark](http://quarktheme.com/)
- [BootstrapWP](http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/)
- [Hybrid Base](http://themehybrid.com/themes/hybrid-base)
- [_tk starter theme](http://themekraft.com/blog/new-wordpress-starter-theme/)
- [Themify Basic](http://themify.me/themes/basic)

Those themes will get you on the start track, they are also frequently updated, so don't worry about code compatibility.

When using a starter theme, it's not always recommended to built using a child theme, not all of the starters are meant to be this way, however building a child theme will allow you to easily update the core theme while continue using your customized one.

[WordPress child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: so what you are actually saying is that the best way to build a theme is to use the 2014 theme and that will be the most updated core code. 
while i can use other themes based on it. or just to edit the actual theme.

Comment: Depending on each theme's documentation, I only used few of them, but all should have the same logic. Roots for example recommends that you edit the code in the way they are providing, and that you shouldn't use a child-theme, if you did so following their documentation, you won't lose your customization if you updated to a new version of their theme when released.

Comment: im building a 9gag website, sort of..
so im not sure how to start.. 
using something like this: http://naked-wordpress.bckmn.com/
or starting with 2014 and move a lot of things.

Comment: It's depending on what's your priorities are, I personally would go with an up-to-date theme, keep in mind that WordPress updates its core frequently and deprecate functions more often..

Answer (score 0):

You should start by building a "Child theme" of your favorite theme, that way you can keep the functions and update of a theme. you should have a look there

http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes